# Bootstrap input 100% width not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a test project just to get myself a bit more familiar with Bootstrap but i've run into a problem with input sizes.

I've placed a simple text input object inside a div tag and the width of this object is automatically set to 100% width. However, the div has been set to show as either half or full screen width (depending on browser size), but no matter what the width of the text box will not go above about 280px. It will happily go smaller than that, but never wider.

I've checked and can confirm that the parent object of this box is the right width, but for some reason the box is refusing to fill it. Does anyone know why this might be happening? The code i'm using is below:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="txt_Address1">Address 1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_Address1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you replicate this in `jsfiddle`?

Comment: Can you please post your extra css code. Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/oumt8u1q and it's working fine.

Comment: So far i'm just using the standard bootstrap css, i've not made any modifications to it it yet. I've just tried it on jsfiddle and it is working as I would expect it to, but it isn't in my local project. I've saved it here https://jsfiddle.net/s3LtLetp/

Comment: Nevermind, I've just located another css file that is setting the max-width of all input objects to 280px. This came pre-included when I created the project. So i've just removed that and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem, I used IE's Developer Tools and the site.css had this:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
     max-width: 280px;
 }
```

Once removed it went 100%.  For me, Visual Studio create the web site project and puts this in Site.css by default.

Comment: You saved the day! I was pulling out my hair for this.